# regex expression to match fraction

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a python regex expression to match following text

```
<   0 | d/dR |    1>
```

I could do something like this

```
r"<\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*xx\s*\|\s*(\d+)\s*>"
```

but can not figure out how to do the fraction part in the middle (`d/dR`) represented as `xx`. Any help? Thank you!!

Comment: What is literal and variable in `d/dR`?

Comment: @mozway : is a number like 0.1031675D-03 for example - sorry is that what you are asking?

Comment: You mean something like `[0-9.]+D-?\d+`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you give us some more examples of the input and the desired output?

Comment: `<\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|\s*(\d+)\s*>` should work, gets `d/DR` no matter what it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
<\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*([^<>]*?)\s*\|\s*(\d+)\s*>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fCP47P/1).

Note the `[^<>]*?` is used here, it matches any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` chars, as few as possible. `<` and `>` are negated because `<` and `>` are left- and right-hand delimiters here, and the negated character class helps prevent matching across `<` and getting unwelcome matched.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fCP47P/1). *Details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*\|\s*` - `|` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `([^<>]*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` chars, as few as possible
- `\s*\|\s*` - `|` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `>` - a `>` char.